# PHP Shopping Cart Array - how do i add sub arrays for multiple options for items in cart

Tags: php, arrays, shopping-cart

I am working on a shopping cart where each product may have multiple options.
I believe the best way to achieve this is to have an array for my shopping cart containing the product id, then a sub array for each option/quantity the user chooses.

Before there were multiple options per product I used this...

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
        "pid" =>  $_POST['pid'],
        "quantity" => $_POST['quantity']
        );
```

This worked fine, now I have multiple options per product how do I add the option and quantity as a 'sub array' - There may be up to 4 options/quantities added per product. I was hoping to do something like this...

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
        "pid" =>  $_POST['pid'],
        [] = array(
             option => $_POST['option']
             quantity => $_POST['quantity']
                         )
        );
```

I know the above is not the right code, just an example to explain my gaol.

End result may be something like...

```
[1]-'product id'
     -option1, Quantity1
     -option2, Quantity1
[2]-'product id'
     -option1, Quantity1
[3]-'product id'
     -option1, Quantity1
     -option2, Quantity1
     -option3, Quantity1
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: if i understand correctly you can name your "options" key with array of options ... you can access to your options in product like a $SESS[cart][1][options][quantity] +1